# Configuring .NET library from unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, configuration, unmanaged

I have a C# .NET library called Foo that produces a Foo.dll file.  It is also configurable via a .config file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Foo.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <Foo.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Server" serializeAs="String">
        <value>localhost</value>
      </setting>
    </Foo.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

What I want to do is call functions in this .NET library from an unmanaged C++ program called Bar and be able to change its configuration from the unmanaged C++ application.  I was able to call Foo functions from Bar by setting classes/interface attributes ComVisible to true in Foo.  However, **I was not able to change the .config file values from the unmanaged C++ application -- Server is always "localhost"**.

Is what I'm trying to do -- configuring a .NET library from unmanaged C++ -- even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is possible, but not a small amount of work.  It's generally easier to create the appdomain and set configuration from the managed world and then create a small 'thunking' layer in managed code to wrap it all up for unmanaged clients.  But since that isn't what you asked for, here is how you could accomplish your goal:

First you will need to import the mscorelib:

```
#include <mscoree.h>
#import <mscorlib.tlb> raw_interfaces_only no_smart_pointers high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")
```

Then bind to the runtime:

```
ICorRuntimeHost runtimeHost;
hr = CorBindToRuntimeEx(
    NULL,   //Retrieve latest version by default
    L"wks", //Request a WorkStation build of the CLR
    STARTUP_LOADER_OPTIMIZATION_SINGLE_DOMAIN | STARTUP_CONCURRENT_GC, 
    CLSID_CorRuntimeHost,
    IID_ICorRuntimeHost,
    (void**)&runtimeHost
);
```

Now startup the CLR and create an AppDomainSetup instance.

```
hr = runtimeHost->Start();
IAppDomainSetup pSetup;
hr = runtimeHost->CreateDomainSetup(&pSetup);
```

Now fill in the setup information as appropriate:

```
hr = pSetup->put_ApplicationBase(_bstr_t(thisFile));
hr = pSetup->put_ConfigurationFile(_bstr_t(configFile));
```

Finally create the domain:

```
hr = __gRuntimeHost->CreateDomainEx(L"ISAPI.Net", pSetup, NULL, &pDomain);
```

Now you can optionally instantiate an object and call methods:

```
hr = pDomain->CreateInstanceFrom(_bstr_t(assemblyFile), _bstr_t("Namespace.ClassName"), &pObjectHandle);
VARIANT vtUnwrapped;
hr = spObjectHandle->Unwrap(&vtUnwrapped);
IDispatch pDisp = vtUnwrapped.pdispVal;
DISPID dispid;
DISPPARAMS dispparamsNoArgs = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
hr = pDisp->GetIDsOfNames (
        IID_NULL, 
        szMemberName,
        1,
        LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
        &dispid
    );

hr = pDisp->Invoke (
          dispid,
          IID_NULL,
          LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
          DISPATCH_METHOD,
          &dispparamsNoArgs,
          NULL,
          NULL,
          NULL
      );
```

Obviously the code fragments above are incomplete; however, if your adept enough at C++ COM the above should provide you with enough information to work it out.  You should note that this is the 'old' (1.x) hosting interfaces which I can attest continue to work through 3.5, I have no idea how/if these work on 4.0.  As of [.Net 2.0 new hosting interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164336%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) were introduced.  I've never had need of anything beyond the 1.x versions, so I never bothered to upgrade any hosting code.

see also: [Hosting Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx)

Comment: @csharptest.net: Thank you, currently trying this now, and also considering the thunking solution.  I will definitely let you know which solution I end up with.

Comment: I've done both, I'll tell you now I prefer the thunking layer in managed code; however, both are plausible solutions.

Comment: Very interesting.  I'm afraid to say I'm unfamiliar with creating this managed thunking layer.  Would it be considered thunking if I make a C++/CLI layer which wraps up the managed configuration (and then calling methods on that C++/CLI layer from unmanaged C++), or am I just wrong about this one?

Comment: @GP How are you currently activating the managed code from C++, via COM InterOp or something else?

Comment: Via COM interop.  You gave me an idea.  I'm currently translating your code above into a C# method that loads the shared C# assembly into a temporary AppDomain, supplying the edited config file, etc.  And it would be THAT method that is called from unmanaged C++.  I'm hoping this works.

Comment: Correct, that was my meaning of a 'managed thunking' layer. Create your domain and object and pass-through the interface calls. Sounds like you got it ;)

Comment: @csharptest.net: I'm still testing this end-to-end, got some other issues with loading the temp AppDomain...at any rate I believe I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

The .Net config system loads `.config` files for EXEs; DLLs do not have config files.

You need to find a different approach.

**EDIT**: You can also create a config file of the form `HostApp.exe.config`, where `HostApp` is the full path to your native EXE.

Comment: On the contrary, dlls do have config files.  For instance, if the consumer of the .NET library in example I've given above is changed from an unmanaged C++ exe to a managed C# exe, you can update the Server of the shared library Foo.dll by copying the .config values of Foo into Bar.exe.config.  Hence, my original question: if it is possible for a .NET consumer to update a .NET dll's config file, would an unmanaged C++ consumer be able to update a .NET dll's config file?

Comment: @GP: That's an **EXE** 's config file. DLLs themselves do not have config files.  The .Net framework will **never** look at `Foo.dll.config`.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, and although I agree that a shared library dll's config file will not be loaded into the AppDomain, that's not exactly what I was suggesting in my comment.  What I'm saying is that if you port (re: copy and paste) C# Foo's configuration into C# Bar's exe.config file, then that enables C# Bar to update the values of a C# Foo's configuration at runtime.  (I'll leave it up to you to test this yourself.)  So again, if it is possible to configure C# Foo's config by C# Bar, can unmanaged C++ Bar do it too?

Comment: I was confused what you meant by "full path" in your EDIT above, seeing that file names cannot contain path characters.  At any rate, I assumed that it was the HostApp's name, but I'm afraid to say that your suggestion in your edit above did not work in the scenario where an unmanaged C++ host calls the C# .NET library.  Server remained localhost.